# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't start with kernel 3.7

Tags: 12.10, kernel

My Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit doesn't start with new kernel 3.7. I try to install the 3.6, but they do not work too. My Mother Board is an Asus M4N68T-M LE, and I have an AMD Phenom II X4 955.

They do boot, but show a lot of errors, and for leave off I need to shutdown the computer. To use the computer, I need to click in "Advanced Config" and choose Ubuntu with kernel 3.5.0-19. Sorry by my English :) and help me

Comment: How did you install the recent kernels? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: "They do boot, but show a lot of errors" and the errors it throws are not important enough to tell us why again?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the kernel?

Did you use .deb packages?

If you did, then install Gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-gtk
```

After this open the .deb files from which you installed you kernel. You need to open all of your packages which were included in this kernel.

After ths run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you want, you may try installing newer versions of kernel (currently the latest is 3.7.1) Use .deb packages for quantal only and install them using Gdebi. Install all of the packages, inluding haders, generic image, image extra.

This is the way, I do it. Maybe there is a shorter terminal way...

Comment: You also may use raring packages

Comment: I install the kernel by the Updates,and today I tryed to install the 3.7.1 in terminal,but don't changed nothing,don't work too.I just don't did 'sudo update-grup'

Comment: @RodolfoCandido Linux 3.7.1 isn't packaged for the current stable release of Ubuntu (12.10) through any official channel. It's not just upgradable to that version "by the updates". Please elaborate.

Comment: Try to download *. deb packages of 3.7.1 for raring here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.7.1-raring/